# Executing a task asynchronously using Combine with Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, combine

I recently started to study the Combine and ran into a certain problem.
First, I will describe what I am doing.
I trying to use Clean Architecture
Here you can see my Repository

```
protocol Repository {
    func test()
}

class MockRepository: Repository {
    func test() {
        sleep(3)
    }
}
```

Then I created UseCase

```
class UseCaseBase<TInput, TOutput> {
    var task: TOutput? { return nil }

    var repository: Repository

    init(_ repository: Repository) {
        self.repository = repository
    }

    func execute(with payload: TInput) -> AnyPublisher<TOutput, Never> {
        return AnyPublisher(Future<TOutput, Never> { promise in
            promise(.success(self.task!))
        })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

class MockUseCase: UseCaseBase<String, Int> {
    override var task: Int? {
        repository.test()
        return 1
    }
}
```

And then in a init block ContentView I did something like that

```
init() {
        let useCase = MockUseCase(MockRepository())
        var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
        useCase.execute(with: "String")
            .sink(receiveValue: { value in
                print(value)
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        print("Started")
        
    }
```

At first, I want to get
"Started"
and then after `sleep(3)`
value "1"

*Now I get
"1" and then "Started"*

Comment: Your `test` is synchronous, publisher started as soon as you attached subscriber, so executes, waits for test, and completed printing result (ie. 1) then in next call prints "Started"... nothing unexpected. If you want non blocking behavior then your task should be asynchronous and then you call promise with result in task's completion block.

Comment: I don't see any SwiftUI in your code.

Comment: By the way, may I suggest my online book? https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/toc.html

Comment: @matt, only init from ContentView. Because in this case, it's not necessary.
Thx for your book I will check it!

Comment: @Asperi, thank you. It's true indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sleep(3)` call runs on the main thread, which means that it blocks any other operations, including the code that prints the "Started" text.

I won't be rambling about how bad it is to block the main thread, this is well known information, but this is the reason you see the behaviour you asked about.

I don't see any thread switching code in your question, so if you wish to achieve some kind of asynchronicity, then you can either go with Rob's solution of using `dispatch(after:)`, or [do the locomotion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POWsFzSFLCE) (the sleep) on another thread:

```
func execute(with payload: TInput) -> AnyPublisher<TOutput, Never> {
    return AnyPublisher(Future<TOutput, Never> { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            promise(.success(self.task!))
        }
    })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'll mention is that you need to hold a reference to `cancellables` or your publisher will automatically be cancelled when you add async processing to the chain. Move it out of your `init` method and into a property.

You can also get rid of the `sleep` and simply chain to a `Delay` publisher on a queue of your choice. I chose `main`.

```
struct SomeThing {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        MockUseCase(MockRepository())
            .execute(with: "String")
            .delay(for: 3.0, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { print($0) } )
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        print("Started")
    }
}

class MockRepository: Repository {
    func test() {
        // sleep(3)
    }
}
```

Another option is to get rid of the `delay`, get rid of the `sleep` and fulfill your promise asynchronously:

```
struct SomeThing {
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        MockUseCase(MockRepository())
            .execute(with: "String")
            .sink(receiveValue: { print($0) } )
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        print("Started")
    }
}

class MockRepository: Repository {
    func test() {
        // sleep(3)
    }
}

func execute(with payload: TInput) -> AnyPublisher<TOutput, Never> {
    return Future<TOutput, Never> { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            promise(.success(self.task!))
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I actually don't need the sleep, delay or etc. I used it only to simulate some work, you know like connect to DB and fetch data. 
I need that my `task` should be asynchronous. `print("Started")` shouldn’t wait for finishing `execute()` 
And probably it can work with Combine.

Comment: I see, then task shouldn't be a property. It should be an async method.